# how to get testng reports on executing junit test

Tags: eclipse

I want to execute test script with JUnit or any other test but want the reports in TestNG reports format:

Is there any way to invoke **`org.testng.reporters`** methods in JUnit framework to obtain TestNG style reports (xml reports, `emailable-reports.html`) on executing the code as JUnit test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can invoke part of testng from JUnit.

What you can do is execute your JUnit test directly (without any changes) from TestNG:
see [section "JUnit tests" from the TestNG manual](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#junit)

Comment: thanks but this is same as executing test script written in junit format via testng but kindly help how to generate testng reports by executing junit Test (I think it can be done by changing the default test result output functionality of junit by importing testng pacakages and invoking methods defined inside them.) kindly help and suggest